# What is the right way to code this Observable to fetch location?

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm writing an observable to help me fetch the user's country code (which is then later passed to a different Observable. This is what I've coded:

```
val tm: TelephonyManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
var countryCodeValue: String = tm.networkCountryIso.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)

disposables.add(Observable.just(countryCodeValue)
      .flatMap {
        if(it.isEmpty()) {
          rxLocation.location()
            .lastLocation()
            .flatMap {
              rxLocation.geocoding().fromLocation(it).map { item -> item.countryCode }
            }
        } else {
          Observable.just(it)
        }
      }
      .subscribe ({
        Timber.i("Got country code: %s", it)
      }, { error -> Timber.i("Got error $error")}))
```

What am I doing here? Taking the country code from the Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE. If it returns empty string, then call [RxLocation](https://github.com/patloew/RxLocation) operators to get the geocoded country code value based on user location.

The **it.isEmpty()** block completely fails and gives an error saying "Type Mismatch". This is surprising since the flatMap should be emitting a string as expected however it doesn't. How to fix this?

Comment: Should the `flatMap` be a `flatMapMaybe`? Looking at the source a Maybe<Address> is the only return type that takes a single parameter argument for `GeoCoding::fromLocation`

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it after reading comment by [Mark Keen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4252352/mark-keen) that I should be using a **flapMapMaybe**.

The working code is now:

```
disposables.add(Observable.just(countryCodeValue)
    .flatMapMaybe {
        if(it.isEmpty()) {
            rxLocation.location()
                .lastLocation()
                .flatMap {
                    rxLocation.geocoding().fromLocation(it).map { item -> item.countryCode }
                }
        } else {
            Maybe.just(it)
        }
    }
    .subscribe ({
        Timber.i("Got %s", it)
    }, { error -> Timber.i("Got error $error")}))
```